# ADB2C : how to get custom claims from external IDP OIDC

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have added a custom IDP (OIDC) as an identity provider in adb2c. Now the client id and secret I have used is configured on IDP side to return all claims but, Iam unable to get those claims when I get a token using a policy on adb2c side 
[image: Token I get directly by logging in to the idp directly has all the claims]

Token I get directly by logging in to the idp directly has all the claims

[image: Claims I get on b2c side]

Claims I get on b2c side

Do I need to do some configuration

Comment: maybe this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow